# Decrypting Hashes

Tags: hash, md5, freebsd

Does anybody know the best way to decrypt FreeBSD hashes? I've been running some through JTR all day now and I couldn't yield a result. Is there perhaps a way to convert a FreeBSD to a normal MD5 hash?

Here are the hashes:

```
$1$LW0BqrMo$7RdAC6dRWhoaSqf81WTDh.
$1$lz2DS3Vy$wxNOu1EBHrcDCYAXbiSLl1
$1$IZSaO//a$0yQcAar4HV/c0ocR7dhnR.
$1$FeUvbH85$poEAS/Nnf/vbRGTzgHtEu.
$1$bMajRVwN$PxIf0SlT16Pt/igAgHeMe1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I ran your hashes through hashcat, and I got the correct original strings. They're listed here:

```
$1$LW0BqrMo$7RdAC6dRWhoaSqf81WTDh.:ethernets
$1$lz2DS3Vy$wxNOu1EBHrcDCYAXbiSLl1:cyptography
$1$IZSaO//a$0yQcAar4HV/c0ocR7dhnR.:bandwidths
$1$FeUvbH85$poEAS/Nnf/vbRGTzgHtEu.:domains
$1$bMajRVwN$PxIf0SlT16Pt/igAgHeMe1:symmetric
```

May I ask what you need them for?

Answer (score 2):

Because FreeBSD is a hashing algorithm and not an encryption algorithm, you can't decrypt it: hashing is one-way.

Comment: I acknowledge that. I was thinking, however, that if there was a way that FreeBSD could be converted into a normal md5 hash, I could look it up for collisions. Also, programs like JTR would run faster if it were in plain MD5 as opposed to FreeBSD.

Comment: I don't know a way to convert a FreeBSD hash to a MD5 hash, but if there would be a way, why? MD5 is also a hashing algorithm, you can't reverse it.

Comment: But there are websites which decrypt md5 algorithms. The ones that do FreeBSD are few and don't work.

Comment: They don't decrypt MD5, they're just crackers. MD5 is a broken hash algorithm, so it's easy to crack for these websites. But I don't think it's possible to convert from one hash to another.

Answer (score 1):

The `$1$` in front of the password indicates it *is* using an MD5 hash. See [crypt(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypt&sektion=3).

As cracker286 demonstrated, those are easy to crack. In FreeBSD 9.x at least the default is to use SHA512 instead of MD5. See login.conf.

Existing FreeBSD installations should update `/etc/login.conf` to switch to SHA512 password hashing and notify the users to change their passwords.

Answer (score -1):

```
$1$FeUvbH85$poEAS/Nnf/vbRGTzgHtEu.:domain
$1$bMajRVwN$PxIf0SlT16Pt/igAgHeMe1:ethernet
$1$IZSaO//a$0yQcAar4HV/c0ocR7dhnR.:cryptography
$1$lz2DS3Vy$wxNOu1EBHrcDCYAXbiSLl1:bandwidth
$1$LW0BqrMo$7RdAC6dRWhoaSqf81WTDh.:asymmetric
```

Comment: This would be a vastly more useful answer if you explained how you reached these answers.